# Doing an Update Ignore in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table where I wish to update some of the rows.  All the fields are not null.  I'm doing a sub-query, and I wish to update the table with the non-Null results.

See Below for my final answer:
In MySQL, I solve this problem by doing an UPDATE IGNORE.  How do I make this work in SQL Server 2005?  The sub-query uses a four-table Join to find the data to insert if it exists.  The Update is being run against a table that could have 90,000+ records, so I need a solution that uses SQL, rather than having the Java program that's querying the database retrieve the results and then update those fields where we've got non-Null values.

Update:  My query:

```
UPDATE #SearchResults SET geneSymbol = (
    SELECT TOP 1 symbol.name FROM 
        GeneSymbol AS symbol JOIN GeneConnector AS geneJoin 
            ON symbol.id = geneJoin.geneSymbolID
        JOIN Result AS sSeq ON geneJoin.sSeqID = sSeq.id 
        JOIN IndelConnector AS joiner ON joiner.sSeqID = sSeq.id 
    WHERE joiner.indelID = #SearchResults.id ORDER BY symbol.id ASC)
WHERE isSNV = 0
```

If I add "AND symbol.name IS NOT NULL" to either WHERE I get a SQL error.  If I run it as is I get "adding null to a non-null column" errors. :-(

Thank you all, I ended up finding this:

```
UPDATE #SearchResults SET geneSymbol = 
    ISNULL ((SELECT TOP 1 symbol.name FROM 
        GeneSymbol AS symbol JOIN GeneConnector AS geneJoin 
            ON symbol.id = geneJoin.geneSymbolID
        JOIN Result AS sSeq ON geneJoin.sSeqID = sSeq.id 
        JOIN IndelConnector AS joiner ON joiner.sSeqID = sSeq.id 
    WHERE joiner.indelID = #SearchResults.id ORDER BY symbol.id ASC), ' ')
WHERE isSNV = 0
```

While it would be better not to do anything in the null case (so I'm going to try to understand the other answers, and see if they're faster) setting the null cases to a blank answer also works, and that's what this does.

Note: Wrapping the ISNULL (...) with () leads to really obscure (and wrong) errors.

Comment: could You be more precise? YOu have a where clause in the update statement where YOu can filter out the null rows, and You can reference the table updated in the joined used for update.

Comment: " YOu have a where clause in the update statement where YOu can filter out the null rows" How?  I'll paste my join below, but I don't see a way to filter for NULL within it, and TSQL won't let me filter for NULL outside of it.

Comment: That RBAR btw, You should avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with UpdatedGenesDS (
select joiner.indelID, name, row_number() over (order by symbol.id asc) seq
from
GeneSymbol AS symbol JOIN GeneConnector AS geneJoin 
            ON symbol.id = geneJoin.geneSymbolID
        JOIN Result AS sSeq ON geneJoin.sSeqID = sSeq.id 
        JOIN IndelConnector AS joiner ON joiner.sSeqID = sSeq.id 
WHERE name is not null ORDER BY symbol.id ASC
)
update Genes
set geneSymbol = upd.name
from #SearchResults a 
inner join UpdateGenesDs upd on a.id = b.intelID
where upd.seq =1 and isSNV = 0
```

this handles the null completely as all are filtered out by the where predicate (can also be filtered by join predicate if You wish. Is it what You are looking for?

Comment: I don't know.  Can that be executed as SQL?  Because I've searched MSDN for UpdateDataSet "SQL Server" and "with UpdateDataSet" for actual examples of using this in SQL, and can't find a single one.

Comment: This works perfectly well. IT's called common table expression. This code is legal

Comment: @Greg - UpdateDataSet is the name that luke has picked to name his Common Table Expression (CTE). So it's not surprising that you can't find references to it on MSDN.

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it look more like an example not like a snippet

Comment: Edited onlce Again. This should fit Your needs

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, where only those rows in #SearchResults that are succesfully joined will be udpated. If there are **no** null values in the underlying data, then the inner joins will pull in no null values, and you won't have to worry about filtering them out.

```
UPDATE #SearchResults
 set geneSymbol = symbol.name
 from #SearchResults sr
  inner join IndelConnector AS joiner
   on joiner.indelID = sr.id
  inner join Result AS sSeq
   on sSeq.id = joiner.sSeqID
  inner join GeneConnector AS geneJoin
   on geneJoin.sSeqID = sSeq.id
  --  Get "lowest" (i.e. first if listed alphabetically) value of name for each id
  inner join (select id, min(name) name
               from GeneSymbol
               group by id) symbol
   on symbol.id = geneJoin.geneSymbolID     
 where isSNV = 0  --  Which table is this value from?
```

(There might be some syntax problems, without tables I can't debug it)

Comment: isSNV is from #SearchResults (it's a bit flag.  I have to use a different table for the first join if isSNV is 1).  While your idea is good, it unfortunately doesn't work.  The problem is that there can be multiple entries in GeneConnector with the same sSeqID, but different geneSymbolIds (that being the whole point of the table, to allow a Result to have a list of associated genes).  All your inner select does is re-create the GeneSymbol table (it already has only one name per id).  So when it runs into an ID will multiple GeneSymbols, it fails.